# PHP equality check not throwing error

Tags: php, syntax-error, equality

I just found the following code in a PHP script and was wondering why it didn't cause PHP to report an error?

```
$current_name == ($type != 3) ? $name : '' ;
```

It was a typo and the code was supposed to read:

```
$current_name = ($type != 3) ? $name : '' ;
```

Comment: You don't need those parantheses [I mean: (($type != 3) ? $name : '' ) ], but you will be effectively comparing $current_name with ($type != 3)

Comment: Why should it, theres nothing wrong with that statement. It returns a boolean value to nowhere. Try `var_dump($current_name == ($type != 3) ? $name : '');`

Comment: @feeela for some reason I though that inline comparison's weren't allowed, as they don't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bizarre bit of code, but only because it is unreadable and useless, not because it is invalid.  It uses the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which is basically a shorthand `if` construct in the format `condition ? if true : if false`.

This code does the following:

1. Check whether `$type != 3`. If `$type` is `3`, return `false`, otherwise `true`.
2. Compare the result of #1 to `$current_name`.
3. If #2 is `true` (i.e. `$current_name == true`), return `$name`. Otherwise (i.e. `$current_name == false`) return `''`.

Of course, all this does absolutely nothing, because there is no assignment in the statement.

Comment: Are you sure it's not actually evaluating as: `($current_name == true)` or `($current_name == false)` depending on `($type != 3)` and then returning either `$name` or `''` based on the `$current_name == x` to void?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, you're right -- I thought `?:` had higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than it does.

Answer (score 3):

It is syntactically correct. The ternary expression is evaluated, then compared to `$current_name`. The result of the whole expression is not used.